# How to get DataAnnotations metadata without dependency on MVC

Tags: .net, data-annotations

Does there exist a helper class in the .NET Framework to easily access metadata from attributes in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace?

I'd like it to be able to encapsulate all the logic of dealing with these attributes, e.g. using `DisplayAttribute` for the display name if present and falling back to `DisplayNameAttribute` if not.

I see ASP.NET MVC has a class `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`, but I was hoping to be able to use the metadata without taking a dependency on an MVC assembly.

Is this possible?